# HTML / CSS block float variations based on width

Tags: html, css

I have several web pages which display data in mostly similar fashion.

Variation #1:  There is one small "legend" table in the upper left of the page, a pie chart in the upper right, and then a data table directly below the legend table, in the same visual left column of the page.

Variation #2:  Same as #1 EXCEPT the data table is very wide and needs the entire page width, and hence needs to be below (rather than to the left of) the pie chart.

Is it possible to create an HTML template and CSS usable by both Variations?

So far, I have tried the following HTML:

```
<div class="filters">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Key</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Woof</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>August</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="graph">
    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/143XJXDEC0B9AHFBPB02.static/samplePieChart.png" />
</div>
<div id="data1">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Foo Column</th>
            <th>Bar</th>
            <th>Bazola</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.filters {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    float: left;
}
.graph {
    Xfloat:right;
}
#data1 {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    float: left;
}
```

I have a JSFiddle where I am trying to work this out (for simplicity, they are both on the same page, but will not be in the real case) at http://jsfiddle.net/LF978/

As it currently stands, it does not work.  My real case has separate pages which work, but result in a lot of duplicated code, which I'd love to remove.

Comment: You said multiple pages right. Give your pages id's and adjust. #page1 #data1 { width: 50% } #page2 #data1 { width: 80% }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way that you could do it by adjusting your CSS:

```css
.filters {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    float: left;
}
.graph {
    float:right;
}
#data1 {
    width: 80%; /* change this to 50% and it will float below the .filters block */
    border: 1px solid grey;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
hr {
    margin: 1.00em 0;
    clear: both;
}
```

Float `.filters` to the left and `.graph` to the right, which you basically figured out.

For `#dataa`, float it to the left and set `clear: left`, which will force `#data` to start right below `.filters` if it has room to the rigth of the `.graph` block.

Otherwise, `#data1` will place itself below the graph is the width is large enough.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/3pQzH/

Note that `hr` needs to be cleared to be below the graph or data table.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try writing some php functions in a separate file for this:

```
<?php
    function getLegend()
    {
        $legend = "
        <div class='filters'>
            <table>
                <tr><th>Key</th><th>Value</th></tr>
                <tr><td>One</td><td>Woof</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Two</td><td>August</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>";
        return $legend;
     }

    function getChart()
    {
        $chart = "
            <div class='graph'>
              <img src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/143XJXDEC0B9AHFBPB02.static/samplePieChart.png'/>
            </div>";
        return $chart;
     }

     function getData()
    {
        $data = "
            <div id='data1'>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Foo Column</th><th>Bar</th><th>Bazola</th></tr>
                </table>
            </div>";
        return $data;
     }
?>
```

You can require that file into your pages and call the functions:

```
<?php
    require_once('filename.php');
?>  

<!--html markup-->

<?php 
    echo (getLegend());
    echo (getChart());
    echo (getData());
?>
```

Make sure that your pages have a .php extension otherwise it won't work!